# Largest Equilateral Triangle in a Polygon

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms

Is there an algorithm to determine the largest equilateral triangle in a convex polygon?

Comment: Related, but not quite the same:  [Maximum circle inside a non-convex polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279478/maximum-circle-inside-a-non-convex-polygon)

Comment: @NovaDenizen Thanks, so maybe make centroid of the triangle as far as possible  from  the vertices and inside the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my other answers to more specific tasks, I offer the following solution that will work for any regular convex polygon:

[image]

1. Draw the long diagonal AE, and draw circles at either end, with radius AE.

[image]

2. Mark H, the point of intersection of the two circles, and draw intervals HA and HE.

[image]

3. Draw a line parallel to HE through C, and mark I, the point of intersection with GA.

[image]

4. Draw a line parallel to HA through C, and mark J, the point of intersection with EF. Draw interval IJ.

[image]

5. Shade $\triangle$CEI, the required equilateral triangle.

[image]

I submit the following example of the construction for an irregular polygon ...

[image]

and make the observations:

1. the inscribed equilateral triangle of maximum area within an irregular polygon will have one side on the polygon's longest side.
2. the inscribed equilateral triangle of maximum area within a regular polygon will have as it's axis of symmetry the longest axis of symmetry of the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

My initial assumption is wrong, and an 80-80-20 triangle provides the coutnerexample.

---

If the triangle is maximal then all 3 vertices have to be on edges of the polygon.  So I'm thinking that it makes sense to approach the problem by iterating over all tuples of 3 edges (filtering out tuples where all 3 edges are the same), assuming one vertex is somewhere on each of these edges, and seeking solutions using each tuple of edges.

Say $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, are the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

If $x_i$ is constrained to be on a line segment between $p_i$ and $q_i$, then $x_i = p_i \alpha_i + (1 - \alpha_i)q_i$ where $0 \le \alpha_i \le 1$ is an interpolation variable that puts each $x_i$ at a proportion of $\alpha_i$ along each line segment.

Define $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ as the vector edges of this triangle ($v_1 = x_1 - x_2$, $v_2 = x_2 - x_3$, $v_3 = x_3 - x_1$).  We have $v_1 \cdot v_1 = v_2 \cdot v_2 = v_3 \cdot v_3$ since the lengths of the sides must be equal.  Substitute the definitions of $v_i$ into these equations, then substitute the interpolation equations for $x_i$ above into that.

Now the equations look like $P_1(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3) = P_2(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3) = P_3(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$ where each $P_i$ is a 2nd degree multinomial.  All solutions of these multinomials obeying the $\alpha$ range requirement form equilateral triangles touching the edge of the polygon.

Any particular instance of these equations could have 0, 1, or 2 solutions, maybe some other number, and possibly an infinite range of solutions (like a regular (or sufficiently symmetrical) polygon with 3n edges).  If you find a finite number of solutions you can just test them to see which results in the largest edge size.  If you find an infinite range of solutions then finding a maximal triangle is more complicated.

~~

Comment: I'm not sure about your very first sentence. Couldn't only $2$ or even $1$ be on the edge?

Comment: Remember that the polygon is convex, so if the triangle's corner points are within the polygon then all points along the edges must also be within the polygon.

Comment: If only 1 vertex is on the edge then you can certainly make the triangle bigger by pushing the other two out to an edge.

Comment: It's also an interesting problem to find the largest equilateral triangle with three touching vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an algorithm:

> DePano, A., Yan Ke, and J. O’Rourke. "Finding largest inscribed equilateral triangles and squares." *Proc. 25th Allerton Conf. Commun. Control Comput.* 1987.

Unfortunately, I do not have easy access to my own article. :-/

---

[image: EqTriSquare]
<sup>(Image from [this link](http://www.math.nmsu.edu/~breakingaway/Lessons/IT/IT.html).)</sup>

Comment: It is not in Math Reviews either.  Can you post a pdf?

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik: I can eventually, but not soon, as it requires a visit to physical archives & scanning.

Comment: I've asked about a special case (probably trivial!) of this question here: [Finding the largest equilateral triangle inside a given triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379188/finding-the-largest-equilateral-triangle-inside-a-given-triangle)

Comment: I got ahold of that paper and uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzeEpFgcFwJbdEE3aDIteVBReUE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: On the second page of the paper, proof of Theorem 1 says “Let $e_a$, $e_b$ and $e_c$ be the three edges of $P$ that contain the corners $a$, $b$ and $c$ of $T$ respectively”. But from the second diagram on [the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379188/finding-the-largest-equilateral-triangle-inside-a-given-triangle), it appears that not all 3 corners of the inscribed equilateral triangle $T$ need be on edges of $P$. Am I missing something?