# The largest equilateral triangle circumscribing a given triangle

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles, area, packing-problem

Seven years ago, one of my many contributions to the [March 2010 edition of Erich Friedman's Math Magic](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0310.html) was a packing of eight circles of unit diameter and one equilateral triangle of unit side length into as small a circle as I could manage.

[image]

To minimise the bounding circle's radius $r$, I had to determine the largest equilateral triangle externally tangent to the three circles adjacent to it, then numerically adjust $r$ until said triangle had side lengths $1$. This is not a trivial problem, and back then I did trial and error in GeoGebra. ($2r=3.4133707107\dots$)

It is easy to see that the circles can be shrunk and the equilateral triangle enlarged about its centre while preserving tangencies, so the problem is equivalent to finding **the largest equilateral triangle $\Delta^*$ where *each* edge is incident to one of $A,B,C$** where $A,B,C$ are the circle centres. The following construction doesn't count since one edge does not meet $\triangle ABC$:

[image]

Now, having reinvigorated my interest in triangles, I believe I have found a construction for $\Delta^*$ for arbitrary $A,B,C$, and am asking here for a more traditional proof of its optimality. My construction proceeds as follows:

1. Construct the first isogonic centre/Fermat point of the triangle, $X_{13}$ in the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers (ETC). That is, construct outward equilateral triangles $A'BC, AB'C, ABC'$ on the sides of $\triangle ABC$, then $X_{13}$ is the concurrence of $AA',BB',CC'$.
2. $\Delta^*$ is (conjecturally) the [antipedal triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntipedalTriangle.html) of $X_{13}$.$^\dagger$ That is, $\Delta^*$ is the triangle formed by perpendiculars at $A,B,C$ of $AX_{13},BX_{13},CX_{13}$ respectively; it is guaranteed to be equilateral because the lines meeting at $X_{13}$ are evenly spaced around it.

[image]

The centroid of the triangle thus constructed is $X_{5463}$ in the ETC, the reflection of $X_{13}$ in the centroid of $\triangle ABC$, and its area is $\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2\sqrt3}+2\operatorname{area}(\triangle ABC)$ where $a,b,c$ are the side lengths. (Alternatively, the area is $2\left(1+\frac{\cot\omega}{\sqrt3}\right)\operatorname{area}(\triangle ABC)$ where $\omega$ is the Brocard angle.)

> How can I prove that my construction actually produces $\Delta^*$, the largest circumscribing equilateral triangle?

---

$^\dagger$Without loss of generality, assume $AB$ is the largest side, and let $P,Q$ be the midpoints of $AC',BC'$ respectively. If $\overline{CP}$ or $\overline{CQ}$ is less than $\frac12\overline{AB}$, my construction will not produce an equilateral triangle actually incident to all of $A,B,C$. In that case, $\Delta^*$ has a side collinear with the triangle's shortest side $s$ and one vertex coincident with the original triangle's smaller angle incident to $s$. If $A,B,C$ are circle centres in a packing problem, this means that a larger equilateral triangle can be drawn by introducing a point contact.

Comment: Largest equilateral triangle *inside* a given triangle is discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379188/finding-the-largest-equilateral-triangle-inside-a-given-triangle but I expect it won't help at all.

Comment: @Parcly "It is equilateral" because the angles of the triangle are 60 degrees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll use $\triangle PQR$ instead of $\triangle ABC$, to avoid some notational confusion.

---

First, a little prep work.

Given $\triangle PQR$, we erect on (directed) segment $\overline{PQ}$ an equilateral triangle $\triangle PQR'$ with a *clockwise orientation*. Similarly, we erect *clockwise* equilaterals $\triangle QRP'$ and $\triangle RPQ'$. As it happens, the lines $\overleftrightarrow{PP'}$, $\overleftrightarrow{QQ'}$, $\overleftrightarrow{RR'}$ meet at a common point, and do so symmetrically. When $\triangle PQR$ itself has a *counter-clockwise* orientation, the three equilaterals are external to it, and the three lines meet at the *first isogonic center* (Kimberling center $X_{13}$); when $\triangle PQR$ has a *clockwise* orientation, the equilaterals overlap its interior, and the common point is the *second isogonic center* ($X_{14}$).

[image] [image]

In any case, we find that any triangle can be positioned such that each of its vertices lies on one of three concurrent, symmetrically-arranged lines. Taking the common point to be the origin, and one of the lines to be the $x$-axis, we can coordinatize $\triangle PQR$ thusly (abusing notation so that $\operatorname{cis}\theta := (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$) as
$$P := p \operatorname{cis} 0 \qquad Q := q \operatorname{cis}\tfrac23\pi\qquad R := r \operatorname{cis}(-\tfrac23\pi) \tag{1}$$ 
where we may assume $q$ and $r$ are non-negative (and not simultaneously zero). One can show that the $x$-intercept of $\overline{QR}$ is $-qr/(q+r)$; consequently, $\triangle PQR$'s orientation depends upon $p$'s relation to that value, and we can write
$$\text{The origin is}\;\triangle PQR\text{'s}\; \left\{\begin{array}{c}\text{first} \\ \text{second} \\ \text{(either)} \end{array}\right\}\; \text{isogonic center if} \;\; p q + q r +r p \left\{\begin{array}{c} > \\ < \\ = \end{array}\right\} 0 \tag{2}$$

---

Now to the topic at hand.

The sides of an equilateral triangle circumscribing $\triangle PQR$ are lines through $P$, $Q$, $R$ with symmetrically-arranged normal vectors, say, $$u := \operatorname{cis}\theta \qquad v := \operatorname{cis}\left(\theta+\tfrac23\pi\right)
\qquad w := \operatorname{cis}\left(\theta-\tfrac23\pi\right) \tag{3}$$
Let $T_\theta$ be the resulting equilateral triangle. I'll forego giving its vertices. The important thing is to compare the sizes of these triangles across all $\theta$, which we can do by computing the areas:

$$|T_\theta| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\;\left(\,p + q + r\,\right)^2\,\cos^2\theta \tag{4}$$

Clearly, $|T_\theta|$ is maximized with $\theta = 0$ (or $\pi$), giving a maximal area

> $$|T_0| = \frac1{\sqrt{3}} (p+q+r)^2 \tag{$\star$}$$

when $u$, $v$, $w$ are parallel to $\overrightarrow{OA}$, $\overrightarrow{OB}$, $\overrightarrow{OC}$. When $O$ is $\triangle PQR$'s first isogonic center (see $(2)$), then $T_0$ matches OP's construction.

Now, while the $T_\theta$ triangles form an infinite family of equilaterals with side-lines containing the vertices of $\triangle PQR$, theirs is not the *only* such family. We get another by changing the signs in $(3)$; that is, by exchanging the roles of $v$ and $w$. The corresponding triangles, $T_\theta'$, have areas given by

$$|T^\prime_\theta| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\left(\,p \cos\theta + q \cos\left(\theta+\tfrac23\pi\right) + r \cos\left(\theta-\tfrac23\pi\right) \,\right)^2 \tag{5}$$

A quick derivative tells us that the critical values of $(4)$ occur for 
$$\cot\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}\,(q-r)}{2p-q-r} \quad\text{or}\quad
\tan\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}\,(r-q)}{2p-q-r} \tag{6}$$
The former corresponds to an area of zero; the latter is maximizing, and we have

> $$\phi := \tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}\,(r-q)}{2p-q-r} \quad\to\quad |T^\prime_\phi| = \frac1{\sqrt{3}} \left(p^2+q^2+r^2-p q-q r-r p\right) \tag{$\star\star$}$$

Comparing $(\star)$ to $(\star\star)$, we have
$$|T_0| - |T_\phi^\prime| = \sqrt{3} \left(p q + q r + r p\right) \tag{7}$$

which hearkens back to $(2)$. So, $T_0$ is maximal when $O$ is the first isogonic center of $\triangle PQR$; otherwise, $T^\prime_\phi$ is.

Importantly, the reader can verify that, at the key angle $\theta = \phi$ from $(\star\star)$, the lines through $P$, $Q$, $R$ with the *direction* vectors $u$, $v$, $w$ (the last two with their signs exchanged) meet at a point; specifically, they meet at $\triangle PQR$'s "other" isogonic center. This tells us that $T^\prime_\phi$ is actually the equilateral triangle obtained from OP's construction relative to that "other" center. Since, by $(7)$ and $(2)$, equilateral $T^\prime_\phi$ maximizes all triangles precisely when the "other" center is the first isogonic center, we have shown that

> OP's construction relative to the first isogonic center is always maximal.

$\square$

---

Here are a couple of animations, showing differently-oriented $\triangle PQR$ (counter-clockwise vs clockwise); the origin (unmarked black dot) is either the first or second isogonic center, respectively. Triangles $T_\theta$ are green, while $T^\prime_\theta$ are light blue.

These images highlight that, while the various equilateral triangles have side-lines passing through the vertices of $\triangle PQR$, not all have $\triangle PQR$ in their interiors; hence, they are not all "circumscribing" in the traditional sense.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your second animation is misleading. Since the vertices $P,Q,R$ run in the opposite direction there, $X_{13}$ and the corresponding circumscribing equilateral triangle should be changed accordingly, but it hasn't. That is, the displayed location of the Fermat point is not correct.

Comment: The condition for $T_0$ to have maximum area can also be written as $p\ge0$ or $p<0,\frac1p+\frac1q+\frac1r\le0$. If $p<0$ and the last inequality of reciprocals is an equality, then negating $p$ (so it is a positive number) we get $\frac1p=\frac1q+\frac1r$. This is precisely the condition for $P,Q,R$ to be collinear (the Fermat point flips as $P$ is moved across $QR$). Thus $T_0$ is in fact the maximum area circumscribing equilateral triangle for _all_ triangles (save for the caveat at the end of my question body). You should probably correct your answer in light of this.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: The images are correct with respect to the coordinatization given in $(1)$. Nevertheless, my description is in error. I wrote that the "first isogonal center" is at the origin, but, for $p<0$ past the threshold of $\overline{QR}$, the origin becomes the *second* isogonal center. I'd intended to describe the point merely as where three symmetrically-arranged lines through the vertices concur, in order to justify $(1)$. Editing on-the-fly seems to have made me a bit lazy, and this had consequences when connecting $T$ and $T'$ to your specific construction. I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: Your construction assumes a certain buildup. Why not locus of 60 to view each side and than need to prove that perpendicular is the solution?

Comment: @Moti: The above argument is what occurred to me, so I presented it. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if there were a simpler way to go about things. (I've been thinking that there might be an approach that makes explicit use of the two isogonic centers from the outset.) I'm not sure I understand your suggestion; of course, you are free to post your own solution.

Comment: I will try to work some details - but your work is impressive with its visual.