# Find area of the largest possible equilateral triangle inscribed in a isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

What is the area of the largest equilateral triangle that can be inscribed in an isosceles triangle?

> There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053733/find-area-of-the-largest-possible-equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-an-isosceles) asked before that might be helpful:

The main problem with this is that sometimes is it unusable. I tried it and it doesn't work.

So here is what I find out from playing around with GeoGebra
$$
l_\max = \frac{3\sin\alpha}{\sin(2\alpha-60^\circ)}.
$$

The formula seems to only work if two of the angles are equal or greater than $60^\circ$.

> [image]

But if we use it with a triangle where two of the angles are less than $60^\circ$, it just doesn't work. Can someone explain why?

1. Why the formula can't be applied to a triangle that
   two of the angle are less than $60^\circ$?
2. If so is there any general formula for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's name vertices, sides and angles of the triangle as in figure below, with $c\le a\le b$ and consequently $\gamma\le \alpha\le \beta$. Let then $PQR$ be the inscribed equilateral triangle, with $P\in AC$, $Q\in AB$ and $\theta=\angle AQP$. Applying the sine rule to triangles $APQ$, $BQR$, it is not difficult to find the side $l=PQ$ as a function of $\theta$:
$$
l={c\sin\alpha\sin\beta\over
\sin\alpha\sin(60°+\theta-\beta)
+\sin\beta\sin(\alpha+\theta)}.
$$

As in the isosceles case, $dl/d\theta=0$ when $l$ reaches its minimum value. The maximum is reached for a limiting value of $\theta$. There are two cases to discuss.

1. If $\alpha>60°$, the limiting values of $\theta$ are reached when
   $Q=B$  (that is $\theta =\beta-60°$)
   or
   $Q=A$ (that is $\theta =180°-\alpha$),
   corresponding to the values of $l$:
   $$
   l_1={c\sin\alpha\over\sin(\alpha+\beta-60°)},
   \quad
   l_2={c\sin\beta\over\sin(\alpha+\beta-60°)}.
   $$
   In this case $l_2>l_1$, hence the maximum of $l$ is given by $l_2$.
2. If $\alpha\le60°$, the limiting values of $\theta$ are reached when $Q=B$ (that is $\theta=\beta-60°$) or $R=B$ (that is $\theta =120°$).
   The first value corresponds to $l_1$ as written above, while the second value gives
   $$
   l_2'={c\sin\alpha\over\cos(\alpha-30°)}.
   $$
   In this case the maximum of $l$ is the greater between $l_1$ and $l_2'$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time sir